# Civibuild Vagrant - drupal-case build?

Tags: civicase, civibuild

Hey all Just found the Civibuildkit using Vagrant - made my day as they have a build that was useful for me to test and work on for my site.

My question is: Is there some one out there that can help me figure out how to create (load) the drupal-case (which is Drupal8 with the latest Civicrm build) without sample data.

I have tried to go through the files to figure it out, but if someone can point me in the right direction it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** BuildKit currently cannot build Drupal 8 sites because of the composer requirement.

To build a Drupal 8 Clean site with CiviBuild you would use the command:

**Note:** *CiviBuild cannot currently build Drupal 8 sites with the demo data.*

`civibuild create d8-master` or `civibuild create <NAME> --type drupal8-clean`

**Note:** This will create a Civi 'master' site using the latest bleeding edge CiviCRM code. To build using a specific CiviCRM version use `--civi-ver` e.g. `--civi-ver 5.6.0`

The full command to create a **Drupal 8**, **CiviCRM 5.6.0** without demo data and named **d8c560** with the URL **http://d8c560.test** is:

`civibuild create d8c560 --type drupal8-clean --civi-ver 5.6.0 --url http://d8c560.test`

The build you refer to `dcase` or `==type drupal-case` builds a Drupal 7 site for testing the CiviCase v5 extension.

#### CiviBuild Docs

The CiviBuild documentation is worth reading:
https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/civibuild/#build-types

#### CiviCase v5

Information on CiviCase v5 (it's awesome!) and the associated dcase build is here:
https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.civicase

Comment: Yes. I did that before I made the post and I get the message when it gets to installing Civicrm that it cannot use “drush” and that civicrm must be installed using “composer” that was why I liked the “drupal-case” but I will do it again maybe I missed something

Comment: So I can confirm that BuildKit "master" cannot build Drupal 8 sites.

Comment: Yes unless someone fixed the Drush install of civicrm to use composer- you will get drupal 8 but you won’t get civicrm. If I am wrong I would love to know how to fix or do it